# Exoplayer Aspect Ratio in Android 7+

Tags: android, aspect-ratio, android-tv, exoplayer, exoplayer2.x

I'm having a problem when making video apps for android tv using exoplayer. In android 6 (Api 23), I can make the aspect ratio like this:

[image]

But somehow in android 7+ (API 24), the result is like this:

[image]

I don't know where is the problem because I'm using the same code and version. I already implement:

```
playerView.setResizeMode(AspectRatioFrameLayout.RESIZE_MODE_FILL);
player.setVideoScalingMode(C.VIDEO_SCALING_MODE_SCALE_TO_FIT_WITH_CROPPING);
```

But the result still same. Please some help. Thank you.

Note:
I'm using exoplayer version: 2.8.4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just figure it out that the problem is with the STB device. When I try in another STB device with the same version (Android 7.1.2), its working fine.